# SpringBoot @ControllerAdvice is working partially

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have tried all the solution provided for this question and didn't worked for me.

Place from where I am throwing exception.

```
public boolean validateToken(String token) {
    try {
         Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtKey).parseClaimsJws(token);
         return !claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date());
    } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new MyException("Expired or invalid JWT token");
    }
}
```

Where it is called

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

CustomExceptionHandler

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ MyException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleJwtException(MyException e) {
        String message = e.getMessage();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

CustomException class

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

`handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported` is working fine but `handleJwtException` is not triggered but instead I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Expired or invalid JWT token
    com.imoney.adapters.JwtTokenProvider.validateToken(JwtTokenProvider.java:74)
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: When is `validateToken` call? Inside a controller method? Or in custom interceptor?

Comment: It is called inside Websecurity config doFilter method where it filters every request to validate the token. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` above `@ControllerAdvice` - it's possible some other error handler is catching your `IMoneyException` before it reaches `CustomExceptionHandler`.

On a side note name `IMoneyException` suggests that your exception is an interface. You may want to change that to avoid confusion in the future.

Edit:

I can't find any literature to support this, but the issue may be that your exception inherits from `RuntimeException`, which makes it an unchecked exception.

Try changing it to:

```
public class MyException extends Exception { 
    public MyException(String message) { super(message); } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't worked though. I have updated the class name as suggested by you.

Comment: I can’t tell whether you mean that it worked or that it didn’t work.

Answer (score -2):

```java
    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);

            return !claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date());

        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }
```

```java
public class JwtAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {

    public JwtAuthenticationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it did work, don't you think catching Exception is sufficient?